# Mishloach Manot - Does the emissary have to be Jewish?

Tags: gentiles, purim, mishloach-manot

I have a very good friend that lives far away from me and I'd very much like to send Mishloach Manot to him.

Is there any rule/halacha/minhag that states that the emissary/third-party (shaliach) of my gift must be Jewish? It is my only option in order to have the gift delivered to my friend.

My plan is to buy everything, pack/assemble properly myself and have a professional courier (non-Jewish) handle the delivery (pick directly from my hands and deliver to my friend's hands). There's no wine so being not mevushal is not a concern.

Would using a non-Jewish emissary be acceptable and help me fulfill the mitzvah or is there something wrong about it?

I'm sorry if this is a repeat but I searched 5-6 similar questions before asking and none addressed my concern in particular.

[Can a shaliach assemble your mishloach manot for you?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56175/can-a-shaliach-assemble-your-mishloach-manot-for-you)

[Can a shaliach buy food to give as mishloach manot?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99756/can-a-shaliach-buy-food-to-give-as-mishloach-manot?rq=1)

Comment: Like any library, Mi Yodeya offers tons of great information, but _[does not offer](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734) personalized, professional advice_, and does not take the place of seeking such advice [from your rabbi](/q/9146).

Comment: possibly helpful to potential answerers in composing their answers: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9F#%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%97_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99_%D7%92%D7%95%D7%99

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an opinion that one may fulfill [sending Mishloach Manot by mail](https://www.chabad.org/holidays/purim/article_cdo/aid/1785917/jewish/Can-I-Send-Mishloach-Manot-Purim-Food-Gifts-by-Mail.htm) providing that one encloses a note requesting the recipient to eat the Misloach Manot specifically on Purim.

If that were the case, one would assume that in the U.S., at least, the postal carrier is probably a Gentile. There's nothing within the linked article stating that the mail must be delivered by a Jew.

Also, [Halachipedia](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Mishloach_Manot#How_the_gift_is_sent) referring to Chazon Ovadyah (pg 145-6), Mekor Chaim 694, Chatom Sofer (Gittin 22b) says that one fulfills his obligation if the messenger is a Gentile.